# org.apache.http compilation errors

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My project has compilation errors related to org.apache.http libraries, as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sZF6.jpg). The project is compiling with api 25.

My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.seffalabdelaziz.crazyman"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 25
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Give proper title to help you better

Answer (score 1):

Support for the Apache HTTP client library was removed from API 23+. See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client. You must remove all references to this library.

As the link above states, you can use [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

So finally its becomes

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.seffalabdelaziz.crazyman"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 25
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```